# What is a (side) current alarm?

Tags: motor-controller, high-side, low-side

On the technical sheet of a motor controller integrating two BTS7960B (picture below), the description of the 8 PINs on the board is as follows:

> RPWM: Forward level or PWM signal input, active HIGH
>
> LPWM: Reverse level or PWM signal input, active HIGH
>
> R_EN: Forward drive enable input, HIGH enable, LOW Close
>
> L_EN: Reverse drive enable input, HIGH enable, LOW Close
>
> **R_IS: Forward drive - side current alarm output**
>
> **L_IS: Reverse drive - side current alarm output**
>
> VCC: 5V power input
>
> GND: Ground

I tried to search for "*side current alarm*" and "*side current*" but all I found was about "*high/low-side current sensing*". Being a newbie in electronics, I'm not sure what is the connection between all those terms.

What is a "***side current alarm***"? How is it used?

[image: Motor driver integrating two BTS7960B]

Comment: Can you add a datasheet link for the board into your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the text is badly typed. If we change

```
R_IS: Forward drive - side current alarm output
L_IS: Reverse drive - side current alarm output
```

to

```
R_IS: Forward drive-side current alarm output
L_IS: Reverse drive-side current alarm output
```

it implies that the alarm is on the "drive-side" of the board as opposed to the control side.

The [BTS7960 datasheet](http://www.robotpower.com/downloads/BTS7960_v1.1_2004-12-07.pdf) says:

> The status pin IS is used as a combined current sense and error flag output. In normal
>   operation (current sense mode), a current source is connected to the status pin, which
>   delivers a current proportional to the forward load current flowing through the active high
>   side switch. If the high side switch is inactive or the current is flowing in the reverse
>   direction no current will be driven except for a marginal leakage current I<sub>IS(LK)</sub>. The
>   external resistor R<sub>IS</sub> determines the voltage per output current. E.g. with the nominal
>   value of 8500 for the current sense ratio k<sub>ILIS</sub> = I<sub>L</sub> / I<sub>IS</sub>, a resistor value of R<sub>IS</sub> = 1kΩ leads
>   to V<sub>IS</sub> = (I<sub>L</sub> / 8.5 A)V. **In case of a fault condition the status output is connected to a
>   current source which is independent of the load current and provides I<sub>IS(lim)</sub>.** The
>   maximum voltage at the IS pin is determined by the choice of the external resistor and
>   the supply voltage. In case of current limitation the I<sub>IS(lim)</sub> is activated for 2 * t<sub>CLS</sub>.

Comment: I think it is much simpler than that. "forward" and "drive" should not be read separately: "Forward drive - side" means "on a 'forward drive' circuit side"